# How to print x-axes labels in pandas.Series.plot()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to visualise my data to understand the data skewness. For that purpose, I use the below and get desired output -

```
df.groupby('owner_team').inc_subj.count().plot.bar(ylim=0)
```

Output -
[image]
My concern is the x-axes labels are shown as numbers, which is the exactly values present. But, my desire is to see the names (string values) corresponding to those numbers.

To give a little bit of background, initially they were string values which I converted to integer values using `factorize()`:

```
df['owner_team'], mapp = df['owner_team'].factorize()
```

I am referencing [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html) Pandas doc but couldn't find the exact parameter to set. 
Tried `labels` but didn't help.

Any pointers please.

ps. Using Pandas v0.23.4 and Python v3.6

Comment: Without sample data it is hard to understand where the names are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look at the [**Pandas plot method**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) (on the DataFrame object), we can see that it returns a matplotlib Axes object.

Try something like this:

```
ax = df.groupby('owner_team').inc_subj.count().plot.bar(ylim=0)

ax.set_xticklabels(df.owner_team)     # if they are still present as strings
```

If you removed that column, go back to your original processing and keep a copy of it somewhere then use that column above, instead.

---

Matplotlib will also generally be able to link to the current/latest plot (figure) that has been created. So using the Pandas plot method, you would need to intercept that.You can then try using standard matplotlib methods (e.g. `plt.xlabels` and so on).

Ther emight be a nice way using the pandas API directly, but I haven't come across that.

Comment: I used `ax.set_xticklabels(mapp)` and got the labels printed. Thanks. :)